# What Maven Dependencies are necessary to run Resteasy version 4.x on Apache Tomcat version 10.x?

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy, tomcat10

Unfortunately I was not able to find any information on how to run a Resteasy based application on Tomcat 10.x. I would appreciate if anybody could show me an example web.xml and pom.xml to make it work.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/resteasy-tomcat-hello-world-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTeasy 4.x is an implementation of JAX-RS 2.0 and uses the `javax.*` namespace. Therefore it will not work with any Jakarta EE 9 server like Tomcat 10 (they use the `jakarta.*` package namespace).

You have two solutions:

- You can use a JAX-RS implementation compatible with Jakarta EE 9. At the moment this means [Jersey 3.x](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/),
- Use the [Tomcat migration tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) to replace `javax.*` with `jakarta.*` in RESTeasy 4.x.